# Prompt user to confirm overwriting data before copying

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy customer data from one worksheet "Raw Data" to another one "Customer Data-Base".

If the data already exists in the "Customer Data-Base" worksheet and prompt the user if they want to overwrite the existing data.

If the user selects yes, the data should be updated for that customer ID only.

```
Sub Copy_Dbase_Code_msgbox()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    Dim Samlastrow As Long
    Dim Msgconfirm As VBA.VbMsgBoxResult

    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    Let r = Rows.Count

    Dim sampleno As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'open book in background
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Muhammad Ali\Desktop\Customer Data-Base.xlsx"

    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Raw data").Worksheets("customers")

    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Customer Data-base.xlsx").Worksheets("Data")

    Samlastrow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    'check for existing data
    Let c = wsCopy.Cells(10, 1).Value

    For r = 1 To lDestLastRow

        If r = c Then

            Msgconfirm = _
              MsgBox("This data already exists, Are you sure that you want to overwrite." _
              & vbNewLine & "Would you like to continue?", vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2, _
              "Confirmation Required")

            If Msgconfirm = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

        Else

            wsCopy.Range("A2").Copy
            wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            wsCopy.Range("B3:B18").Copy
            wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

            wsCopy.Range("A21").Copy
            wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            wsCopy.Range("B22:B37").Copy
            wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

            wsCopy.Range("A39").Copy
            wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            wsCopy.Range("B40:B55").Copy
            wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

        End If

    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It'd be great if you can describe what you are seeing as far as error or unexpected results, etc.

Comment: I'm thinking your issue is with your `if` statement right after the `Msgconfirm` question. The way you have it set now, the `Else` on the following line is *actually* acting as an else for `If r = c Then`

Comment: ```If Msgconfirm = vbCancel Then Exit Sub``` If there is already data and they want to overwrite that, then it will just move onto ```next r```. Not sure if that  is the issue

Comment: If my last idea was right, just moving `exit sub` to the next line should fix your problem